# Android/PhoneGap local build not working after removing Admob Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I added this plugin: https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob

with the command line in PhoneGap 3.3

However I decided to use a different plugin. After attempting an uninstall:

```
cordova plugin remove com.google.cordova.plugin.AdMobPlugin
```

I rebuilt the app and launched it on my device. The application compiles fine but the information I display (an RSS feed) does not display the data. Instead, my error catch displays a message. BUT, when I re-install the plugin, it works!

I have not changed any part of the `config.xml` file, or `Android Manifest` so I am lost as to why this is happening. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin adds some authorisations in AndroidManifest.xml when it's added :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I think that your issue is that when you remove the plugin, it doesn't know if this authorisations were already there (added by an other plugin or present by default) or not and removes the lines in all cases.

I suggest you manually edit platforms/android/AndroidManifest to add the lines you need.

If you have no plugins in your project, you will at least need to add `android.permission.INTERNET` which is present in default cordova project and needed for any app accessing network.

If you have FILE plugin or any other plugin needing to write to sdcard, also add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Thank you! I was stressed! I made a zip file of the application before testing the plugin, so when things went south I tried to replace the non-working file with the saved copy - which did not work either! Do you know if I can clone the application for a backup?

Comment: a zip from the root of the project should do the job, strange it didn't work for you.

Comment: When I tried to build the application with the unzipped file, the CLI responded: "Not recognized as a cordova project" or something similar to that.

Comment: maybe you forgot to cd in the project

Comment: Maybe that was the problem because what I did was right-click the application and zipped it. Maybe I should go through the command line instead?